# two component can display in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two component in the same work space in reactjs but just one is displaying

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo, { ReactComponent } from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
class App extends React.Component {
  render() { 
    let helloWorld = 'Welcome to good programming React';
     return ( 
      <div className="App">
         <h2> {helloWorld}</h2>
          </div>
           ); 
          }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root')); 
class   Form    extends React.Component {   
    constructor(props)  {       
    super(props)                
    this.state  =   {   username:   ''  }
    this.handleChange   =   this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit   =   this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange(event)   {       
  this.setState({   value:  event.target.value  })  
  }
  handleSubmit(event)   {
  alert(this.state.username)
  event.preventDefault()    
  }
  render()  {   
  return    (   
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.username}  onChange={this.handleChange} /> 
      <input    type="submit"   value="Submit"  />
      </form>               
      )     
    } 
  }
export default (App,Form)
```

output from browser gives just the form.how can i do to display both App and form

Answer (score 1):

Call `<Form />` inside App component and then export your App component

```
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are mounting the node `<App/>` but it does not contain your `<Form/>` component.

You just need to call `<Form/>` inside your `<App/>` component like this

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() { 
    let helloWorld = 'Welcome to good programming React';
     return ( 
      <div className="App">
         <h2> {helloWorld}</h2>
         <Form/>
      </div>
     ); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might not be understanding how React works, and you might be confused with this code

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

What this code essentially does is renders the `App` Component into the element in the `index.html` with the id `root`. The reason why your second component is not rendering is because it is not experiencing a `ReactDOM.render` nor is it included in the `App` Component.

By convention, `App` component should be the only component experiencing `ReactDOM.render`, and all the other component to be rendered must be inside the `App` component. Just like what @sudo97 is saying

Answer (score 0):

ReactDOM.render function needs to have the Root component or the parent component which is to be passed as a first parameter.

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here App is the root component, you can include `<Form />` inside of the App component to render both the components.

Answer (score 0):

You are not rendering the `<Form />` component. Heres the simplest solution code to solve your issue:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./App.css";

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { username: "" };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert(this.state.username);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.username}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let helloWorld = "Welcome to good programming React";
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h2> {helloWorld}</h2>
        <Form />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

export default App;
```